# Seeking satellite image API

Tags: image, gis, satellite

I’m seeking a satellite image API which I can call with lat/long, date, resolution, among other things, and pull a satellite image to analyze.

What are some go-to APIs for this purpose? I’m willing to pay as I anticipate heavy usage.

Answer (score 1):

`ESRI` has many public satellite images consumable using their `ArcGIS API for JS` .

Here's an example : `https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-basemapgallery/index.html`

As long as you need to display layers from public services and add some graphics on it (Polygons points etc) , you can use it for free . Otherwise if you are planning to create your own maps , then you should pay or find other `GIS` opensource solutions .

Answer (score 0):

A similar post on the same topic can be found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/seeking-satellite-imagery-providers). A list of satellite APIs can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200622070732/https://www.programmableweb.com/category/satellites/api). Note that this is an archived version, as the original link is down.